# Trigger compilation to JS from Scala in PlayFramework

Tags: scala, playframework-2.1

I have an idea (not new though) to make a compilation scala code to `JavaScript`.  Basically I would like to use `Scala` where now `Coffee Script` is used in `PlayFramework 2.x`.

It seems it is not so hard to make it happen. Let's say I have a file `/managed/Foo.js.scala`. If something has changed in this file, when I refresh a page it triggers the compilation to js. And then, as result I can see updated `assets/javascripts/Foo.js` file.

**So, the question is**: how to trigger complication by browser-refresh event in `PlayFramework`?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but digging around [here](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/tree/master/framework/src/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala) might help. Also, have you played around with [Scala.js](http://www.scala-js.org/)?

Answer (score 0):

Not necessary the answer but a [direction](https://github.com/jamesward/play-auto-refresh) where is the effort to do this. I will play around this.

About Sccla.JS, I guess it might be critical if I develop application that needs to be run on mobile. Several BMs of JS might deal breaker to use Sccla.JS

Comment: Note that Scala.js now uses the google closure compiler to optimize its code size. The example reversi application is now below 300KB.